# Would you go for SVG based renderer or HTML5?

Tags: html, svg

We are in the research phase of a new project which will be used in the advertising arena. Users create a bunch of items that will play in different regions on the screen and can then swap out animations (images/texts etc).

We are pushing for an HTML5 solution which will be responsible for the rendering but a new proposal is to just use SVG (and SMIL).

I know you can embed SVG content in HTML5 pages and there are numerous links comparing the canvas and SVG.

What I need to know is what are the pros and cons of going for a solution which is based on HTML5 compared with a solution that is based solely on SVG?  Also for the long term plans of the project, I can see HTML5 as allowing so much more.

Also I am not sure what tooling support is available for users using SVG. Most of items must be templatable (changing text/images), is this at all possible?

TIA

JD

Comment: Your question is unclear, with HTML5 you can embed SVG directly with the `svg`-tag. Do you mean SVG vs Canvas?

Comment: No, I know we can embed SVG in HTML5. We are looking at what we use as the rendering technology. Either we go for an SVG renderer or we go for HTML5.

Comment: @JD: I think you are confused: SVG is vector graphics, while HTML5 is a HTML document format and they don't have much in common. But HTML5 has a Canvas element that you can use JavaScript to render graphics.

Comment: I am not from a graphics background so apologies. What we have to decide is create an advertising tool (show ads on the screen). What I understood was HTML5 with css3 will give us a animations to show the ads. Then someone mentioned why not just build an SVG renderer whose sole purpose will be to show the ads.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently had an opportunity to try [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/), an SVG-based solution, and [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/), an canvas-based solution.  Both provide emulation on browsers that don't support the primary format: Raphaël uses VML on IE, and Flot uses [excanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/).

Both SVG and canvas have advantages and disadvantages.  Both can draw shapes, paths, and embed images, but canvas can do pixel-level manipulation and can draw a lot more sprites quickly, which is why it's becoming popular for HTML5 games.  SVG has more powerful paths, although you'll have to learn the syntax.

SVG has another really interesting advantage: elements on a chart are DOM nodes, so it can use browser mouse and click events as well as add, remove, or change an individual node without redrawing the whole chart. Doing the same thing on a canvas involves manually keeping track of the locations of every visual element and redrawing the whole canvas when stuff moves. (Canvas does let you do double buffering and caching stuff sop it is possible to redraw it quickly, but the logic of keeping track of where everything is is still on you.)

For that reason, I think SVG is a better choice for interactive graphs and charts, while canvas is more appropriate for advanced graphics.  In either case, cross-platform compatibility is a concern and a abstraction layer is indicated.

Comment: Thanks. With the charts examples, say I have 5 charts on the screen at the same time and each chart is driven dynamically (i.e. a number of ajax requests need to get the data and then update the various dom elements), would this affect the rendering of the charts?

Answer (score 1):

SVG is potentially more search-engine friendly **and** accessible than HTML5 <canvas>, in that SVG elements and text can be (potentially -- not sure if they actually do!) indexed and read out to a screenreader, user whilst <canvas> is initially just a bitmap and would need additional content to be created if one of these ads was to be presented as part of a web page. OTOH, if it's a game-like tool that's not for content creation then perhaps that's not an issue ... perhaps give more details?

Comment: Google does index SVG.